# Do browsers assure that if an inline css property has not been set, the value of "element.style.property" will always be a empty string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example:

```
<xxx id="myid" ...></xxx>
```

If no code or nobody sets the inline css properties of element "xxx", then document.getElementById("myid").style.property always equals ""?

Do w3c standards or all browsers assure it?

Answer (score 1):

On Blink based browsers, it seems to always set it to an empty string.

MDN recommends clearing them by setting them to `null`, which then isn't an empty string, but upon testing this in a blink based browser, it seems to reset to an empty string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

On some browsers, when a CSS property hasn't been set, it is literally `undefined`, which is quite different from `null` or `""` (an empty string).

You can force some consistency between all browsers and updated values by coercing to an empty string.

```javascript
document.getElementById("myid").style.property || ""
```

## Edit - New properties

CSS is rapidly changing, with new properties appearing frequently. As such, it got me thinking, what happens in blink based browsers with unrecognised properties.

The answer is not consistent with known properties, and instead, they are `undefined` if not set. Equally these can be set to `null`.

I would recommend using falsy checks when appropriate to solve this problem.

Comment: On chrome it is ""

Comment: I agree, on the latest blink based browsers it seems to be an empty string. However, the specification doesn't force it. I'll fetch some more information and update accordingly.

Comment: @JialeWang - I have updated to provide some context and a reference, but certainly in blink based browsers you can assume it to always be a string.

Comment: Thanks! But this is really nasty. I think it's a potential bug source for many web front-end application.

Comment: OK. As a developer myself, I like to code in a way that will handle these scenarios, so these days I use `?.` to access properties of objects that might not exist and `?:` to default falsy values where all falsy values are to be treated the same. They are fairly common things to do, and designed for this purpose. As for whether the values should ever be anything other than a string, the specification doesn't make it a requirement. Remember you might try to access a CSS property that doesn't exist in slightly older browsers, which will then be `undefined`.

Comment: I think you mean `??`, not `?:`. `?:` is used for the conditional operator and requires an expression between `?` and `:`.

Comment: Actually, I meant `||` as a falsy fallback. I've been swapping and changing between JS and PHP too much recently.